# How to call a filter function inside v-for loop by key value to filter date from datetime

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am printing a json object inside an array. I have the key values too. I wanna call a filter function for the datetime key, so that i can display only the date. But i don't know at which point i can call the filter function... Any ideas ? Thank you very much

```
<td v-for="x in selectedColumns" v-bind:key="x.value">
    <div v-if="x.value='datetime' in dateFormat(props.item[x.value])"> {{ props.item[x.value] }} </div>
</td>
```

Comment: use `===` or `==` inside `v-if`

Comment: i am getting now an error because the "in" ... I am new in vue and don't know how to call my dateFormat function (inside methods section) to return only the date from datetime inside the v-for loop ...

Comment: Can you give `response` data set for example? It's too tough to understand what you are trying to acheive

Comment: I think you are coding wrong. because you have condition if x.value === 'datetime' while you are calling  > in dateFormat(props.item[x.value]) so it will return result, and if result true or false you can use like this. 


v-if = "x.value === 'datetime' ? dateFormat(props.item[x.value]) : false"